# Form Field "amount" Validation alert $ dollar sign is not allowed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

what would be a simple Javascript way to validate the "amount" field to make sure a user does not add $ the dollar sign in html form field.

Comment: Add a `change` event handler that tests the field's value and either removes any dollar signs or displays an error message.

Comment: I know how to check if form field is empty but but not sure on correct format to check if a $ is added then alert

Comment: If the value is in a variable `fieldValue`, then `if (/\$/.test(fieldValue)) { alert("There's a dollar sign") }` tests it using a regular expression. Or `if (fieldValue.indexOf("$") > -1)` works if you don't know regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy way: use `<input type="number"/>`

It's widely supported and won't allow non number inputs.

Comment: I have used and tested <input type="number"/> but it is ugly and because our form works different with some calculations, the up and down numbers do not work. I am only changing this old form because PayPal no longer allows us to pass the $ into their new cgi script.

Comment: Use this css to hide up down buttons on input type number
 input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
input[type="number"] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

Comment: because I like simple best - I just don't know <input type="number" is a simple way ...and if I can figure out how to css the up and down, may be the best way to go. I have added it again to the test page, but will have to look at css'ing it later today, when I get back... in the mean time if anyone has any other ideas please let me know. I will remove that page link from here after I am happy with solution. I only added it so you all can see

Comment: I did not know you could style that number input field so in summary the best way was to add the input type  number and use some css..... thanks for the help.. this works perfect   input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to simply use `<input type="number"/>`.

**Alternative**

Let's assume the input field is "$45". Assuming it is stored as a string we can loop over each character to find the dollar ($) sign and if it's not there then the user has entered correct value.

Algorithm.

```
function isDollarExist(input){
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if(input.charAt(i) === '$') return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression.

```
var dollarInput = '$100';
var numberInput = '100';

/\$/.test(dollarInput); // True
/\$/.test(numberInput); // False
```

Comment: No need for the `g` flag.